# can't implement vue.js 2 components

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am totally new to vue.js, reading from the text book `"Getting to know Vue"`.

I am stuck at the components page, as the sample code just didn't work for me.
`Every time I open the HTML file, it returns a blank page.`

I searched in google, yahoo, vue documents, their examples also didn't work for me. It looks very strange I can't run this code correctly.
Appreciate help to get this to work.

Code sample
Version is `vue.js is 2.7.14`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head></head>    
    <body>    
      <script src="vue.js"></script>
      <script>
        Vue.component('our-header', {
          template: `<h1>App Header</h1>`
        });
      </script>    
      <div id='our-header'>
        <our-header></our-header>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe,you has't inited the vue object in script code.Using “var app = new Vue()” and bind it with a element which as a render container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Vue is in “unmounted” state, without an associated DOM element. vm.$mount() can be used to manually start the mounting of an unmounted Vue instance.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head></head>    
    <body>    
      <div id='app'>  
      </div>
      <script src="vue.js"></script>
      <script>
        const OurHeader = Vue.component('our-header', {
          template: `<h1>App Header</h1>`
        });
        var app = new Vue({
          render: (h) => h(OurHeader),
        }).$mount('#app')
        
      </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.7.14/vue.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head></head>    
    <body>    
      <div id='app'>  
      </div>
      <script>
        const OurHeader = Vue.component('our-header', {
          template: `<h1>App Header</h1>`
        });
        var app = new Vue({
          render: (h) => h(OurHeader),
        }).$mount('#app')
      </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to change

```html
<script src="vue.js"></script>
```

To

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

To see if it can work. I guess you didn't import VueJS well.